# Use single driver instance in multiple methods & classes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, driver, instance

I have created 2 packages each contains a java class file. The Utility class in 1st package initiates the driver & closes the driver with methods- `launchDriver()` & `closeDriver()`. In the 2nd package-Example java class file contains call to these methods. The driver is successfully launched using `launchDriver()` but when the driver is passed to `closeDriver` method, the value becomes null...

Please provide a solution.The code is as shown,..

```
public class Utility {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String driverpath="E:\\Drivers";

    @Test
    public static WebDriver launchDriver(final String browser,final String url){
        if(browser=="firefox"){
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }else if(browser=="chrome"){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath+"\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }else if(browser=="ie"){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverpath+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }else{
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }
        return driver;

    }
    @Test
    public static WebDriver closeDriver(WebDriver driver){
        Utility.driver=driver;
        driver.quit();
        return driver;

    }
}
```

class Example in tests package

```
public class Example{

    @Test
    public static void launchConfig(){
        Utility.launchDriver("chrome", "https://www.google.com");
        //Utility.launchDriver("firefox","www.google.com");
        Utility.closeDriver(Utility.driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is ever assigned to `Utility.driver`, so it is null when you pass it to closeDriver. You should review the usage of static variables and a local variable with the same name as a class variable.

Comment: @Saket..cn you put up some code to assign the driver in Utility..I understood that you are asking me to create a constructor in Utility. ..Moreover if I want to use "this" keyword in here..Will it be helpful and how do we apply it..

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract test class and have your test classes extend that. your abstract test class might look like this:

```
    public abstract class Abstract test {
      //delcare driver
      public static WebDriver driver;

      //Assign the correct driver
      @BeforeSuite
      public void webdriverSetUp() {
       if(browser=="firefox"){
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if(browser=="chrome"){
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        } else if(browser=="ie"){
            WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } else{
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        }
      }

      //call getDriver() in your tests  
      public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
      }
    }
```

Just dont forget your probably going to want to clear all cookies between test methods.